# How to get rid of a top margin of my body element?

Tags: html, css, angular

I've a blank angular app, with only an AppComponent. I edited the styles to remove padding & margin, but I keep getting the body(check by setting a background-color to it) that has some kind of margin in the top.

Here is a running example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-44yyz1?file=src/styles.css

Why the red background doesn't start on the top?

seems like a stupid question(probably is) but with the inspector and everything, I cannot see what is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the H1 element has a margin by default.

You can just remove it:

```
h1 {
   margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: `h1 { margin-top: 0; }`

Comment: That's it, but I'm not sure to understand, why a margin on the h1 affect the body? Because the margin should be between the h1 and the div, then the div& body should have the correct(red) color from the top of the page, no?